# Css HTML And rotated divs

Tags: css

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.screencontainer{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
xxheight: auto;
xxmax-width: 90%;
align-items: middle;
}

.foundations-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.foundations-content{
display: block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.foundations-button{
display: inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color: blue;
margin: auto;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.search-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.search-content{
display: inline-block;
height:50px;
width:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
color: white;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.titlebar{
display: block;
width:404px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="screencontainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="titlebar">1</div>
<div class="foundations-wrapper">
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>

</div>
    <div class="foundations-wrapper">
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="search-content">1</div>
    <div class="search-content">1</div> 
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Bit of an 'interesting' problem. I'm trying to do a really simple layout template in html/css. (it's simple as it's destined for a confluence page so the less fancy the better)

The layout is relatively simple - The aim was to have three menu containers side by side. The third and final box of the three was to have rotated menu buttons.

I face two problems with what my code produces.

**1) In the third yellow box you will see that I have two rotated divs. The space between them is massive and the container for them behaves... oddly - it expands massively.. What I wanted was for the container to scale in size with the content as there should be five menu buttons in there, not just two. And they should be spaced out with really only 2-5 px between them.**

**2) I can't seem to get the containers to centre vertically within the parent container.**

(feel free to ignore the title bar. I was going to scale that across later when finished)

Can someone assist me here?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.screencontainer{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
xxheight: auto;
xxmax-width: 90%;
align-items: middle;
}

.foundations-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.foundations-content{
display: block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.foundations-button{
display: inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color: blue;
margin: auto;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.search-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.search-content{
display: inline-block;
height:50px;
width:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
color: white;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.titlebar{
display: block;
width:404px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="screencontainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="titlebar">1</div>
<div class="foundations-wrapper">
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>

</div>
    <div class="foundations-wrapper">
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="search-content">1</div>
    <div class="search-content">1</div> 
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the `xxheight` in the code ? are you able to create a snippet with your code ?

Comment: Try changing the size of search container instead of rotating the div. https://jsfiddle.net/r4q1u1f4/4/

Comment: The XX<code> is just redundant code I was trying out to try and solve my problems. They can be deleted.

Comment: On rotating the div: I needed a div with rotated text. This is my problem :(

Comment: Why does it need to be rotated?

Comment: Design Mainly. I'm not sure what would be a satisfactory answer to this. If there's a way of rotating text without rotating the div, that would be easier

Comment: I did that, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? I rotated paragraph tags within the div.

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">





















  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>








    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">




  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

  <title></title>
















<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){



}




</script>


</head>

<body>



<style>
.screencontainer{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
xxheight: auto;
xxmax-width: 90%;
align-items: middle;
}

.foundations-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.foundations-content{
display: block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.foundations-button{
display: inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color: blue;
margin: auto;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.search-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
xxheight: auto;
margin: auto;
}
.search-content{
display: inline-block;
height:200px;
width:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}

.titlebar{
display: block;
width:404px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
</style>


<div class="screencontainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="titlebar">1</div>
<div class="foundations-wrapper">
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>

</div>
    <div class="foundations-wrapper">
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="search-content" style="
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
"><p style="
    transform: rotate(90deg);
">
    1</p></div><div class="search-content"><p style="
    transform: rotate(90deg);
">
    1</p></div>


</div>
</div>  




  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "r4q1u1f4"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>





</body></html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4q1u1f4/7/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.screencontainer{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;

align-items: middle;
}

.foundations-wrapper{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
margin: auto;
}
.foundations-content{
display: block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.foundations-button{
display: inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color: blue;
margin: auto;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
.search-wrapper{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
padding: 10px;
height: 200px;
margin: auto;
}
.search-content{
position: relative;
top: 75px;
display: inline-block;
height:50px;
width:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
color: white;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.titlebar{
display: block;
width:404px;
height:20px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="screencontainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="titlebar">1</div>
<div class="foundations-wrapper">
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>
    <div class="foundations-content">1</div>

</div>
    <div class="foundations-wrapper">
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="foundations-content">
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
            <div class="foundations-button">1</div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="search-content">1</div>
    <div class="search-content">1</div> 
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies - delay in refresh. Yes that's exactly it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! May i ask what's your goal with this design? :) I might have an even better solution (Responsive maybe) depending on what you're trying to do.